# Can't run c++ environment for anaconda

Tags: python, linux, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have used `conda install xeus-cling -c conda-forge` to setup the c++ environment.
When I input `jupyter kernelspec list` it's OK

```
Available kernels:
  c          /home/UserName/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/c
  python3    /home/UserName/anaconda3/envs/mixed/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
  xcpp11     /home/UserName/anaconda3/envs/mixed/share/jupyter/kernels/xcpp11
  xcpp14     /home/UserName/anaconda3/envs/mixed/share/jupyter/kernels/xcpp14
  xcpp17     /home/UserName/anaconda3/envs/mixed/share/jupyter/kernels/xcpp17
```

But after I opened my jupyter notebook and create a helloworld.ipynb using `C++17`, the environment cannot load. Here's the output:

```sh
[I 14:33:08.063 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), new random ports
/home/littleblack/anaconda3/envs/mixed/bin/xcpp: /home/littleblack/anaconda3/envs/mixed/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found (required by /home/littleblack/anaconda3/envs/mixed/bin/../lib/libxeus-cling.so.0)
/home/littleblack/anaconda3/envs/mixed/bin/xcpp: /home/littleblack/anaconda3/envs/mixed/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found (required by /home/littleblack/anaconda3/envs/mixed/bin/../lib/libxeus.so.1)
[I 14:33:11.073 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (2/5), new random ports
/home/littleblack/anaconda3/envs/mixed/bin/xcpp: /home/littleblack/anaconda3/envs/mixed/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found (required by /home/littleblack/anaconda3/envs/mixed/bin/../lib/libxeus-cling.so.0)
/home/littleblack/anaconda3/envs/mixed/bin/xcpp: /home/littleblack/anaconda3/envs/mixed/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found (required by /home/littleblack/anaconda3/envs/mixed/bin/../lib/libxeus.so.1)
[I 14:33:14.083 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (3/5), new random ports
/home/littleblack/anaconda3/envs/mixed/bin/xcpp: /home/littleblack/anaconda3/envs/mixed/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found (required by /home/littleblack/anaconda3/envs/mixed/bin/../lib/libxeus-cling.so.0)
/home/littleblack/anaconda3/envs/mixed/bin/xcpp: /home/littleblack/anaconda3/envs/mixed/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found (required by /home/littleblack/anaconda3/envs/mixed/bin/../lib/libxeus.so.1)
[I 14:33:17.095 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (4/5), new random ports
/home/littleblack/anaconda3/envs/mixed/bin/xcpp: /home/littleblack/anaconda3/envs/mixed/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found (required by /home/littleblack/anaconda3/envs/mixed/bin/../lib/libxeus-cling.so.0)
/home/littleblack/anaconda3/envs/mixed/bin/xcpp: /home/littleblack/anaconda3/envs/mixed/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found (required by /home/littleblack/anaconda3/envs/mixed/bin/../lib/libxeus.so.1)
[W 14:33:20.105 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restart failed
[W 14:33:20.106 NotebookApp] Kernel 985da6a1-a8a7-4797-b423-ebd2f5136aca died, removing from map.
[W 14:34:05.178 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from 985da6a1-a8a7-4797-b423-ebd2f5136aca
```

I have tried to install gcc, update conda packges, but it stays the same.
I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Comment: Possible issue of mixing **defaults** channel and **conda-forge**? Check `conda list` to see that most packages are coming from `conda-forge`. In particular, make sure `libstdcxx-ng` is from `conda-forge` (I suspect that is the package with the `GLIBCXX` issue, but not totally sure). If not, try `conda install -c conda-forge conda-forge::libstdcxx-ng` or `conda update -c conda-forge libstdcxx-ng`.